# eclipse does not save files in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

eclipse does not create file borrarSecuence.txt in the hadoop file system, but  when I execute it with `hadoop jar /home/javier/input/Untitled.jar com.main.SecuenceFile` in shell create me the file `borrarSecuence.txt`

```
package com.main;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Reader;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Writer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SecuenceFile extends Configuracion implements Serializable{
    Path filePath;
    public SequenceFile.Writer writer;
    public SequenceFile.Reader reader;
    public SecuenceFile() {
        super();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecuenceFile s=new SecuenceFile();
        s.inicia();

    }
    public void inicia()
    {
        this.filePath=new Path("borrarSecuence.txt"); //user/javier/borrar.txt
        guardar(this.filePath);
          leer(this.filePath);
    }
public void guardar(Path filePath)
{
    try {
          //   writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf,filePath, Long.class,
                   //   String.class);           
             writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf,
                     Writer.file(filePath), Writer.keyClass(Text.class),
                     Writer.valueClass(IntWritable.class));       

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {           

            writer.append(new Text("key1"), new IntWritable(1));
            writer.append(new Text("key2"), new IntWritable(2));    
            writer.append(new Text("key3"), new IntWritable(3));
            writer.append(new Text("key4"), new IntWritable(4));
            writer.append(new Text("key5"), new IntWritable(5));
            writer.append(new Text("key6"), new IntWritable(6));    
            writer.append(new Text("key7"), new IntWritable(7));
            writer.append(new Text("key8"), new IntWritable(8));
            writer.close();
         //   IOUtils.closeStream(writer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
public void leer(Path filePath)
{
    try {       
        reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(conf,
                Reader.file(filePath));
        Text key = new Text();
        IntWritable val = new IntWritable();

        while (reader.next(key, val)) {
            System.err.println(key + "\t" + val);
        }

    reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A4rb.png)

I'm using hadoop-eclipse-plugin-2.6.0.jar, Hadoop 2.9.2, java version "1.8.0_191", eclipse Oxigen

Comment: Perhaps you should go to that log4j URL in the message an setup logging to see the real error (if one exists)

Comment: And I don't think Eclipse is the problem. You could do `new Path("hdfs://<namenode>:<port>/user/javier/borrarSecuence.txt");`, and it should work

Comment: I had set   this.filePath=new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/javier/output/Secuence.txt"); and I had  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryUtils.getDefaultRetryPolicy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/RetryPolicy

Comment: Are you using Maven/Gradle to download Hadoop dependencies?

Comment: I am not using Maven I use eclipse

Comment: it works well out of eclipse from the console of the hdfs

Comment: can it be some configuration of the mapReduce installed in eclipse?

Comment: Configuration conf=new Configuration();
 conf.set("io.serializations","org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization," 
   + "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization");

Comment: Maven (or any dependency management tool) needs to be used within Eclipse (your IDE) to download and setup what classes and methods are able to be used in your code. Just setting a configuration doesn't do anything special required for the code to actually run (Hadoop is not just a single JAR file to load), and the `eclipse-plugin` is **not** what you need